# Does the number of hands on the Weasley clock ever change?

Tags: harry-potter

In The Burrow there is a clock with the members of the Weasley family on,it shows where the family members are at all times, if one of the Weasleys get married do their partners/any possible children get added to the clock.We know that there was originally 9 hands each representing each member of the Weasley family. Does this ever change for example when (SPOILER ALERT) Fred dies or when a new family member is born.

Comment: I think the answer is simply "We don't know". See [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/189127/who-is-included-on-the-weasleys-clock?rq=1).

Comment: @F1Krazy I read the question you sent me a link to and even though the answer didn't answer my questione I can see why you said that we don't know.If anyone has an answer then please answer it down below.

Comment: Changed title so it's hopefully different to the previous question.My first question so I don't know if it's worked out properly.

Comment: I don't mind if there is just theories posted about this I would just like an answer.

Comment: I would delete this but it was the first question I posted so it is important to me so I can't

Comment: I voted to lease closed because an answer to that question should rather be included in the duplicate-target, in order to prevent info from being scattered around. However, I don't think there is a need to delete this question, it serves at a point of entry to the dupe-target and is rather clear.